# How can I add a registered trademark symbol (R) to an asp:RadioButton control declaritively?

Tags: asp.net

I want to show a registered trademark symbol (i.e. an 'R' in a circle) in a label on a web page. But I want to add it in the design view markup not in the code-behind file.

Is there an equivalent of &copy?

EDIT: Any idea how I use this when defining a radio button as it doesn't work when applied to the Text property of an asp:RadioButton control?

Answer (score 4):

®:

```
&reg;
```

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_entities.asp

Answer (score 2):

You mean like this ?

```
 &reg;
```

(taken from [Latin-1 entities](http://htmlhelp.com/reference/html40/entities/latin1.html))

Answer (score 2):

hold <kbd>alt</kbd> and type in `0174` to get ®